# Jar file with hibernate dependency not executable with jdk 9+ (openjdk 12)

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, openjdk-12

I'm not able to run .jar file with: `java -jar`. I got the exception saying:

*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)*

Although the project compiles and run well directly in IDE.

---

Current approach:

**pom.xml file:**

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version> 5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version> 5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version> 1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        --enable-preview
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-staging</id>
            <url>http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/staging/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I'm using openjdk 12, can't use oracle for docker images. Not sure, what I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say, you cannot run the program via java -jar. What is your classpath?

Comment: @triplem https://imgur.com/a/R6ivhnf. The jar fails to run, same occurs in docker container

Comment: TBH, that does not show, how your classpath looks. Have you build an Uber JAR with maven? Otherwise you do need to put all your dependencies (including transient ones) from the pom in the classpath.

Comment: @triplem Yes, I did  package with Maven

Comment: An Uber JAR? in your pom there is no hint to this one. I guess you are doing a "normal" mvn clean package. Which is fine, but does not include all necessary dependencies. Please use the maven shade plugin or something similar to create an uber jar, if necessary.

Comment: It's the case - it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do seem to build a JAR by using "mvn clean package" (or similar). This JAR file does not contain any dependencies, but just your own classes and resources. To be able to call "java -jar YOURJAR.jar" you do need to create a so called Uber-Jar, which contains all dependencies (from the maven pom). This can be created using the Maven Shade plugin.